# Why don't you get reputation when people upvote your comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, upvotes

Why do you receive up votes on one of your comments do you not receive any reputation? What is the reasoning behind this.

I understand that you can get reputation from lots of other methods, but this seems to be one one where you interact with the question can receive no "reward" for doing so.

(I did a search of the meta to see if this had been asked before but could not find anything, apologies if this has been asked already).

Comment: A) comments can't be downvoted, so they would become an easy source of upvotes. B)comments are second class citizens on Stack, meant only to ask for clarification on a question.... they really shouldn't provide rep when upvoted.  C) you definitely get a reward.... "poster asks unclear question" -> "I use comments to clarify question" -> "poster clarifies question" -> "I now can answer and get rep"

Comment: @Patrice What you say is fair. But then what is the point of being able to up vote comments in the first place?

Comment: no clue. Maybe to know which comments to hide when there's too many in a thread?

Comment: The point of voting is not that users get reputation; but to signal other users which content is more useful. Same with comments as with regular posts.

Comment: @JackU just think about it. When you see a comment with 50 updoots next to it, your eyes are drawn to it, correct? That's the point. I tend to updoot comments which I think are important for other people to read too.

Answer (score 14):

As has been pointed out in the comments on the question:

1. Comments can't be down-voted (only up-voted or flagged). If they were to confer reputation then a down-vote mechanism would need to be added.
2. Comments are 2nd class citizens on Stack Overflow. Their ideal use is to request clarification on a question, point out an error in an answer, etc. have that issue addressed and then get deleted.
3. The point of up-votes is to be able to apply a crude but effective filter if there are many comments. These that have the most votes are displayed preferentially.

Comment: I thought the main reason for upvotes on comments is to avoid "me too" duplicated comments...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov there is that, but the up-votes are definitely used to decide which comments to display when there are a lot.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it would not be the first time that a tool has multiple no mutually exclusive purposes.

Comment: They also get deleted pretty frequently. If you did get rep from comment upvotes you'd probably lose most of it soon after.

Answer (score 4):

If you count a badge as contributing towards overall reputation then you do: you get the [Pundit badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/94/pundit) for leaving 10 comments with score of 5 or more.

[image: Pundit badge]